# Display full page image after image is loaded

Tags: jquery, css, window, domcontentloaded

How do I display a image only after it loads but the rest of the page shows normally? On each page I have something like this `<html class"page-name">` and the css is as follows `html.page-name { background: url(images/page-name.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; }`

I tried to do the javascript as `$(window).load(function(){ $('html').fadeIn(1500);
});`

but this obviously doesn't work because the hole page is blank until the image is loaded. I want the background to be black until the image is loaded and than replace it to the black background. I also tried `$(window).load(function(){ $('html').addClass('page-title'); });`
where `page-title` class has transition effect but also doesn't work.

How do I achieve this, having a black background and replace it with an image after it fully loads ?

Thank you.

Comment: I've just copied your question title to Google and voila: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331261/show-all-images-only-after-their-complete-load Tailor it for your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load image dynamically and then on its onload add it to the background

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
      // image  has been loaded
      $("html.page-name").css("background-image","url('"+image_url+"')");
    };
    img.src = image_url;
})
```

Comment: if we have multiple images to load like this how will we get **image_url** for each when loaded?

Comment: @mebjas I did not get your question properly. For multiple images you have to write separate onload handlers

Answer (score 1):

#### jQuery:

```
// Wait for page load
$(function() {
  // apply background image class to body (fade over 500 milliseconds)
  $('body').addClass('page-title', 500);
});
```

#### CSS:

```
.page-title {
   background-image: url('/path_to/image.jpg');
 }
```