# preload images on website so they dont scroll down the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, performance, preloading

my webpage, http://wizardsofthegrimoire.com/, has a background image. I was able to get the file size of the website so that it loads fast enough, but when a user comes to the site for the first time the background image is displaye as it is loading. 
I'm wondering if there is some way to delay the display of the image until it is fully loaded using css.

Comment: Is the image file a JPG?

Comment: Would this help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120053/display-full-page-image-after-image-is-loaded

Comment: Ya that is what I want I think, but I have trouble implementing it. Im not very good with Javascript. Can you explain how to input it into my code?